# struct declaration

Tags: c, struct

What is the difference between these 2 ways of declaring a struct?

First way:

```
struct x {};
```

Second way:

```
struct _x {} x;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first defines only the type `struct x`. The second defines the type `struct _x` *and* defines a variable of that type named `x`.

Though it's probably not what you had in mind, names starting with an underscore like `_x` are reserved at file scope, so unless this is inside some other scope, the second has undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

The second way declares a variable named the type `struct _x` *and* a variable of this type named `x`. The first one only declares the type `struct x`.

The second way is essentially the same as

```
struct _x{};    // define a type
struct _x x;    // allocate a variable of type struct _x
```